# two database and two login url in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

Im very new to mvc 5 and other MVC,
I create a web app in VS2013 but for login and membership, I used MVC4 methods.
I want to have two different data base for Amins and usual Users,
for some controller of my project I put

```
`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
 [InitializeAdminMembership]`    (only accessible by Admin)
```

and for some other I put

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
```

when an unauthenticated user want to access to the first one,should redirect to login page for Admin,and second one should redirect to login page for Users,
I put this to web.config

```
 <appSettings>
//remove for clarity
<add key="LoginUrl" value="~/Admin/Login"/>
<add key="LoginUrl" value="~/User/Login"/>
 </appSettings>
```

but only one of `<add ..../>` works,
by paying attention to 2 separate data base(Admin and Usual User) how can I redirect unauthenticated people to appropriate login page?
in other words how can I have two login Url?is that possible?

thanks every body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create your own Custom Action Filter attribute, which is called whenever an action is called, and in that you will check the role of logged in user and will check if the action that user is trying to access is for user admin , if for admin redirect to admin login action else allow to access action.

Here is the reference links:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx